# Xcode- Can we symbolicate a crash without the device?

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash

I have recently recieved a crash report from apple-On running the app in iphone 5.I donot have an iphone5 with me,i have only iphone 4.Then can I symbolicate the crash using iphone 4 or without using device can I symbolicate it??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: You don't use any device to symbolicate a crash report.

Comment: @rmaddy I dint get u??

Comment: What don't you get? Simply load the crash report into Xcode.

Comment: i tried loading the crash report but it do not get symbolicated.Then i have read somewhere that we have to add the device to symbolicate.Even tried the link given by @Rushabh but  dint work!!